# Why @PetiteInject cannot inject service in DecoraManager?

Tags: jodd

I have a DecoraManager implementation : AppDecoraManager, and want to inject a service e.g.: FooService as:

```
@PetiteInject
FooService fooService;
```

When resolveDecorator() is called I want to use fooService to determine some parameters, but it has null value.

What could be the reason for this, and how could I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecoraManager` is created by the servlet container, in `DecoraServletFilter`.

At the moment, there is no integration with existing Petite IOC, so you have to do the following:

- First, you need to have a public static reference to `PetiteContainer`. Store it during the creation of container, for example.
- Override `createDecoraManager()` in your implementation
- Use `PetiteContainer.wire(this)` in your implementation of `DecoraManager`.

That is the only way to do so, so far.

The alternative would be this:

- Register `DecoraManager` as `@PetiteBean`.
- Again, get the static reference to `PetiteContainer`
- In `createDecoraManager` use `PetiteContainer.get()` to get the instance.

In the first example, `DecoraManager` gets just wired; in the second example, it gets stored in Petite container, too.